# JSON.Net errors when deserializing data posted from AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a pretty long form with about 9 or so pairs of radio buttons, bound by AngularJS. They look like this:

```
 <input type="radio" name="didPay" data-ng-model="model.didPay" value="True" /> 
 <input type="radio" name="didPay" data-ng-model="model.didPay" value="False" />
```

By using browser dev tools, I can see that by default model.didPay is set to "{ }", I'm guessing to keep the bound radio buttons from having an unintended default selection. If I click on an option and then manually set the value of model.didPay to " { } " it in fact resets the selection back to their original state. So far so good.

My problem is that some of the radio buttons are hidden based on previous selections, so in the best case scenario I will be posting at least 3 or so of these radio buttons as " { } " to the server.

On the server side, I have WebApi and JSON.Net doing the deserialization. While deserializing, JSON.Net throws an error:

```
Exception {"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'didPay', line 1, position 91."}  
System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException}
```

I was hoping that by setting the destination variable to string, JSON.Net would hopefully assign null or an empty string if it encountered "{ }". However, this isn't the case as it correctly errors out when it encounters a new object instead of a string.

My question is: how are people dealing with this AngularJS radio button behavior when POSTing data? Any ideas of how I can get JSON.Net to serialize that value into anything useful?

Glad to provide more details if need be.

**Additional details:**

I have a model where for example didPay is a bool? property and a viewmodel where it's being mapped as a string.

```
public class Model
{
    public bool? DidPay { get; set; }
    // rest of the props
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string DidPay { get; set; }
    // rest of them props
}
```

My WebApi controller is taking the viewmodel as a parameter and doing the model binding magic:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ViewModel data)
{
    var mappedData = Mapper.Map<ViewModel, Model>(data);
    // save the data
    // return response
}
```

Kiran's suggestion gave me an idea. I changed the type of my ViewModel's property to object and now it no longer complains about the deserialization. So that's one problem fixed. My current issue is mapping the JObject to a `Nullable<bool>` with Automapper. I'm hoping that's an easy thing to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automapper custom type converters did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DeserializeObject to convert the json object(string) into the type of .net object.

Example : converting a json string object into a Dictionary object.

```
Dictionary<string, object> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(strJsonresults);
```

Comment: That gave me an idea. Changed the receiving type to object and Json.Net was able to do the deserialization and WebApi's model binder was able to bind to the model. Thanks for the suggestion!